# SAS Proc PSMATCH vs R Matchit Propensity Score Matching Samples

Tags: r, sas, propensity-score-matching

Is it possible to produce the same matches between SAS Proc PSMatch and R Matchit? They produce the same predicted probabilities/distance, and the same number of subjects per group, but the samples are different. I read three things regarding this:

1. MatchIt will set [priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637354/propensity-score-matching-in-r) for matching the treated to the controls; really great explanation btw.
2. MatchIt will [shuffle](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260918/different-results-after-propensity-score-matching-in-r) the observations prior to matching, so to reproduce the matched sample, one should set a seed
3. MatchIt will [randomly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/nearest-neighbor-matching-in-r-using-matchit) select the control subjects when they fall into the caliper.

Additionally, can anyone explain the difference in the way that caliper is defined? In SAS I have: stat = lps caliper(mult = stddev) = 0.5 ...is the equivalent in R just: distance = 'logit', caliper = 0.5?

Example: [SAS Data](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_code_psmchex4.htm&docsetVersion=14.2&locale=en)

SAS Code:

```
proc logistic data = school;
class Music(ref='Yes') Gender/ param = glm;  
model Music= Gender Absence;
output out = school_prob prob = pred_prob;
run;


proc psmatch data = school_prob region = allobs;
class Music Gender;
psdata treatvar = Music(Treated='Yes')  PS = pred_prob;
match method = greedy(k = 1) stat = lps caliper(mult = stddev) = 0.5;
output out(obs = match) = psmatch_dat matchid = MatchID;
run;
```

R Code:

```
library(haven)
library(MatchIt)
## save the data 'school' from sas as music.sas7bdat
school <- read_sas(music.sas7bdat)

school$Music <- ifelse(school$Music == 'Yes', 1, 0)
school$Gender <- ifelse(school$Gender == 'Female', 1, 0)
school$Music <- as.factor(school$Music)
school$Gender <- as.factor(school$Gender)

hold_match <- matchit(Music ~ Gender + Absence, data = school, method = 'nearest', distance = 'logit', caliper = 0.5)

psmatch_dat <- match.data(hold_match)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The exact same matches? Most likely not because they use different algorithms under the hood so to speak. The matches should be equivalent. If you're uncertain of the stability of the estimate, do a bootstrap estimate in each application and see if the intervals are different. In that case you would have an issue, IMO.

Comment: @Reeza appreciate the answer, I double checked it and I'm going to have to say they don't match. Apparently MatchIt samples from the treated observations that have ties and samples from the controls as well when you have a caliper set.

Comment: Your confidence intervals for your parameter estimates don't overlap at all? Obviously the cases themselves won't match but I'd expect the estimates to be similar after bootstrapping.

Comment: The confidence intervals match, but the overall matched samples differ. I've accepted it as something to be true. You cannot replicate the matched sample from proc psmatch in matchit because of the underlying mechanisms. The treated units are not guaranteed to be the same between the two software, additionally even if you get the same treated units, the controls will vary due to how the algorithms choose their match.

Comment: That is correct. With different algorithms you cannot expect the same matches. Even in greedy matching, a different sort order can cause different matches. You need to understand how your algorithm is working in detail for Case Control. But if the CI match you can be fairly certain the methods are equivalent.